# VBA Vlookup formula, value does not appear in cell

Tags: vba, excel, formula, vlookup

My problem is that when i put this code in VBA:

```
Sub formula_vlookup()
                                'MONTHS
ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16).Select
With ActiveCell
    .formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(" & .Offset(0, -16).Address(0, 1) & ",'CZ support'!$A:$AA,2,0)), _ 
"""",(VLOOKUP(" & .Offset(0, -16).Address(0, 1) & ",'CZ support'!$A:$AA,2,0)))"

End With
End Sub
```

It works perfectly ( i mean , it gives me the value of the cell that is "vlooked up" but the problem is that it does not display that value in the cell, so the only way to know if its a value there is making a SUM of the cells that contain this formula.

how can i manage this problem? 
Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to check:

- Name [CZ Support] (with a BLANK in the middle) may be invalid ... I can't create that in XLS2010
- check that the name exists (Name manager or just try to select it from the drop down left of formula bar)
- Try entering the same formula (with `.Offset(...)` expanded to actual cell addresses) directly in worksheet cell(s)
- Try replacing the "" in the FALSE part of the `=IF(...)` by some text (e.g. "not found") to see if you're caught by an exception
- Try replacing the last VLOOKUP argument (0) by TRUE or FALSE as per the documentation
- Try assigning the formula to a string variable first and examine it in the debugger window (or do a Debug.Print thereof)
- pasting your code "as is" gave me an error - my VBA doesn't like the line splitting underscore in the formula generation